# Define parts of a predicate across several modules

Tags: module, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm trying to write a predicate `move/3` which handles several kinds of terms, each kind of which is defined in a separate file.  I'm trying to use modules for this, because the files contain other predicates which should be namespaced appropriately.

So, I've created a module `cat.prolog` with contents:

```
:- module(cat, [move/3]).
:- multifile(move/3).

move(cat(C), P, cat(C2)) :-
   ...
```

Similarly for `dog.prolog`.

And `main.prolog` with:

```
:- use_module(['cat.prolog'], [move/3]).
:- use_module(['dog.prolog'], [move/3]).

(various predicates that use move/3 and expecting the clauses from all imported modules to be applicable.)
```

Trying to run this in SWI-Prolog:

```
?- ['main.prolog'].
%  cat.prolog compiled into cat 0.00 sec, 4,800 bytes
ERROR: Cannot import dog:move/3 into module user: already imported from cat
Warning: /home/edmund/main.prolog:2:
        Goal (directive) failed: user:use_module([dog.prolog],[move/3])
% main.prolog compiled 0.00 sec, 10,176 bytes
true.
```

At this point I can use `dog:move/3` and `cat:move/3` but not `move/3`.  It works for the `cat` case but not the `dog` case.

I get the feeling there's a really obvious way to do this.  I've tried combining modules and imports and multifile directives in many ways and still not found it yet...

Comment: Have you tried declaring move/3 to be multifile in your `main` module as well?

Comment: I did try but it didn't make any difference, still the error about it being already imported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The multifile/1 syntax is simple, but the [documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28multifile%29/1) lacks a simple example...

I created 3 *modules* files: `pets.pl`, `cat.pl`, `dog.pl`.

```
:- module(pets, [test/0, move/3]).
:- multifile move/3.
move(A,B,C) :- writeln(pets-move(A,B,C)).
test :- forall(move(A,B,C), writeln(move(A,B,C))).

:- module(cat, []).
:- use_module(pets).
pets:move(A,B,C) :- writeln(cat-move(A,B,C)).

:- module(dog, []).
:- use_module(pets).
pets:move(A,B,C) :- writeln(dog-move(A,B,C)).
```

Note the relevant syntax `Module:Pred :- ...` in the 'dependent' files

```
?- [cat,dog].
%  pets compiled into pets 0.00 sec, 3 clauses
% cat compiled into cat 0.01 sec, 7 clauses
% dog compiled into dog 0.00 sec, 3 clauses
true.

?- test.
Correct to: "pets:test"? yes
pets-move(_G41,_G42,_G43)
move(_G41,_G42,_G43)
cat-move(_G41,_G42,_G43)
move(_G41,_G42,_G43)
dog-move(_G41,_G42,_G43)
move(_G41,_G42,_G43)
true.

?-
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising.  It's interesting that you have the the cat and dog modules include the pets module instead the other way round like I had it.

Comment: This solution is a good example of using multifile predicates but doesn't give you a simple solution to ask e.g. a cat to move as all clauses for the predicate are in the pets namespace.

Comment: @PauloMoura: your comment hits the core of the problem. There is an obvious solution I'm missing ?

Comment: I did posted a working solution. As of now is voted down. But back to multifile predicates. I don't think there's any simple and obvious solution. A multifile predicate always belongs to a single namespace (possibly the pseudo-module user). Thus, its clauses can, of course, be scattered but access is always trough the same module prefix (even if implicit).

Comment: @PauloMoura: thanks for the explanation. BTW I'm not the downvoter, I think Logtalk it's most promising way to object orientation in Prolog...

Comment: In some cases, you may be able to use an include/1 directive with he file with common stuff but then you face another issue: the lack of separation between declaring a predicate and defining a predicate. This clear separation exists e.g. in Logtalk (which also provides protocols/interfaces as first class entities) but not in Prolog module system such as de one provided by SWI-Prolog (which is basically the de facto standard one).

Comment: Hum... how about using an export/1 directive inside a pets file that's included in the cat and fog files using an include/1 directive? That's likely the close you can get to share what can be interpreted as a predicate declaration.

Answer (score 4):

A second working solution, this time without using the Logtalk extension to Prolog, following up my comment about using the `include/1` directive:

```
----- common.pl -----
:- export(move/1).
---------------------

----- cat.pl -----
:- module(cat, []).
:- include(common).

move(cat).
---------------------

----- dog.pl -----
:- module(dog, []).
:- include(common).

move(dog).
---------------------

$ swipl
...
?- use_module(cat, []), use_module(dog, []).
% cat compiled into cat 0.00 sec, 4 clauses
% dog compiled into dog 0.00 sec, 4 clauses
true.

?- cat:move(X).
X = cat.

?- dog:move(X).
X = dog.

?- module_property(cat, exports(Exports)).
Exports = [move/1].

?- module_property(dog, exports(Exports)).
Exports = [move/1].
```

Like in the Logtalk solution, multifile predicates are not the answer.

It should be noted that, in most Prolog module systems, including SWI-Prolog, any module predicate can be called using explicit qualification as in the queries above. But using a file to hold the common bits have still two advantages: (1) it makes explicit in a single place the common bits and avoids *source code* duplication; (2) well behaved applications should only call exported predicates and there are tools that can detect violation of this principle. On the down side, an included file is only a first class entity of you consider files itself as such. Care must also be taking when loading the modules that include the common bits file as usage of e.g. `consult/1` or `use_module/1` will result in conflicts:

```
?- [cat, dog].
% cat compiled into cat 0.00 sec, 4 clauses
ERROR: import/1: No permission to import dog:move/1 into user (already imported from cat)
% dog compiled into dog 0.00 sec, 4 clauses
true.
```

In practice, this solution may result in most or all module predicates to be called using explicit qualification.

Comment: Nice answer (+1), the relation among export/1, include/1 is very elusive. But I'm not sure this solution fits OP' question.

Comment: My interpretation of the OP' question is that he wants to have a common interface and different implementations for that interface (but it would help to have more input from him). Thus, the most clean solution is the Logtalk one, which currently sits with zero votes and even had negative votes earlier. But down-voters provided so far zero working solutions. Logtalk was designed with this kind of problems in mind. Prolog modules were designed for zero-overhead, not designed to solve this kind of problems elegantly or at all. So, an elusive module solution is the best you can do.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is to define a Logtalk protocol (i.e. an interface) for declaring predicates such as `move/3` and then define any number of objects implementing this protocol. You can run Logtalk using most Prolog compilers, including SWI-Prolog. For example:

```
:- protocol(pets).

    :- public(move/3).
    ...

:- end_protocol.


:- object(cat, implements(pets)).

    move(A, B, C) :-
        ...

:- end_object.


:- object(dog, implements(pets)).

    move(A, B, C) :-
        ...

:- end_object.
```

Assuming that each entity above is defined in its own file, e.g. `pets.lgt`, `cat.lgt`, and `dog.lgt` you can then do:

```
$ swilgt
...
?- {pets, cat, dog}.
...
? - cat::move(A, B, C).
...
```

Logtalk supports both prototypes and classes/instances so you can define any kind of hierarchy/program structure that fits your application. It's also likely a more clean solution than subverting multifile predicates to have different predicate implementations for different entities.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It's not quite what I want but Logtalk sounds interesting so I'll read up on it.