# Knowledge representation in Prolog - how to store data?

Tags: database-design, prolog

as I got critic concerning my data structure in Prolog I asked here the experts for alternative solutions.

As example, I have a data set of recipe decription in XML

```
<recipeml fileversion="13.8.2014">
  <recipe>
    <head>
      <title>Green Soup</title>
    </head>
    <ing-div type="titled">
        <title>soup</title>
        <ingredients>
          <ing>
            <amt><qty>500</qty><unit>gramm</unit></amt>
            <item>pea</item>
          </ing>
          <ing>
            <amt><qty>200</qty><unit>ml</unit></amt>
            <item>cream</item>
          </ing>
          ...
        </ingredients>
    </ing-div>  
    <directions>
      <step>Do something, cooking ....</step>
      <step>Next do again something...</step>
      ...
    </directions>
  </recipe>
  <recipe>
   ...
  </recipe>
  ...
</recipeml>
```

I choose to store it in Prolog as iterative element-tree using lists:

```
database([element('recipeml',[version=0.5], 
    [element('recipe',[],
        [element('head',[],
            [element('title',[],['Green Soup']
            )]
        ),
        element('ing-div',[type=titled], 
            [element('title',[],['soup']),
             element('ingredients',[],
                [element(ing,[],
                    [ element(amt,[],
                        [ element(qty,[],['500']), element(unit,[],[gramm]),]),
                    element(item,[],['pea']) 
                    ]),
                element(ing,[],
                    [ element(amt,[],
                        [ element(qty,[],['200']), element(unit,[],[ml]),]),
                    element(item,[],['pea']) 
                    ])
                ]
            )]
        )]
    ),
    element('recipe',[],...
    )] 
)]).
```

What I want to do is to look easily for recipes based on user input. 
The user might give an ingredient or part of the recipe name as input.

Actually I ran throught the elements by

```
ask_element(Name, Child, Parent) :-
        (
            member( element(Name,_,Child),Parent)
        ;
            member( element(_,_,NewParent),Parent),
            [_|_] = NewParent,
            ask_element(Name, Child, NewParent)
        ).
```

I got all recipes with a special ingredient by

```
 findall(RTitle,
            (
            ask_element('recipe',RKnot,Knot),
            ask_element('item',TmpIng,RKnot),
            contains(TmpIng,Ingredient),
            [Ing|_] = TmpIng, % avoid brackets [Egg]
            define_xml_knot(['head','title'],_,RKnot,TmpRTitle),
            [RTitle|_] = TmpRTitle % avoid brackets [Soup]
        ,Bag),
```

My result is then a list of the recipes titles. If a list of ingredients is entered I need
a second analysing step to get the recipe with the most matching ingredients. Maybe this is 
not really Prolog style?

One idea, following the remark by Paulo Moura (thanks), is to arrange the data as

```
recipe(IDnumber,'Green Soup',ingredients(item(500,gramm,'pea'),item(200,ml,'cream')),steps('Do something','Next step do again something')).
```

I am not sure if this would be really help. Looking for a recipe with a certain ingredient I have to look again step by step in each recipe through every item if the ingredient I am looking for (or part of the word) is contained. And if I want to add a new descriptor, e.g. "`level(easy)`" I have to change all data calls as the number of element in `recipe()` changes. With the `element(element...)` construction I do not have to change the calls. 
But the response would be better, by returning only the IDnumber, then I get the whole recipe in one "call" (`recipe(123,X,Y,Z)`) for further processing. Actually I 
return as response "string text in a list" as you see it in "Bag" above...

It is my first application in Prolog, so I am not very familiar with an adquate data storing. I would be grateful for every hint.

Comment: In my suggestion, ingredients and steps would have a single argument, a list of, respectively, ingredients and steps. I.e. using your example, `recipe(IDnumber,'Green Soup',ingredients([item(500,gramm,'pea'),item(200,ml,'cream')]),steps(['Do something','Next step do again something'])).`. Having ingredients and steps as compound terms with recipe-depending arity would just complicate processing for no benefit. This will also mirror more closely the XML structure you present (assuming that's your intention).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access from Prolog information represented in XML files, Carlo's solution is a good one.

But let's assume that you want all recipes represented in Prolog. One solution, as you described, is to use one fact per recipe, with a structure that best fits the most common data access patterns in your application. As you also noticed, looking for e.g. recipes using a specific ingredient or requiring a specific test will not be efficient as you must go from recipe fact to list of ingredients (or steps) and then do a linear search on that list (you could use a binary search tree instead of a list but I doubt the likely low number of items would justify it computationally). Moreover, adding new descriptors like `level/1` in your question requires changes to be potentially propagated to all code that accesses the recipe data. Taking this issues into account, it might be worth to look into use a module or an object representation for the recipes. The idea would be that each recipe would be represented by a module or object with one predicate per attribute. with this representation, the computational cost of accessing an ingredient would be the same as the cost of accessing the recipe name or one of its steps. When e.g. searching for recipes with a specific ingredient, the necessary step of enumerating all recipe modules or objects is a cheap operation. Adding a new descriptor is easy with an object representation and can also be hacked with a module representation (essentially, you would simply modify the recipe interface, possibly adding a default value for the new descriptor). It's also possible to have a mixed representation and there are cases where such a solution is justified. It would be easier to advice if you share more details on the access or reasoning that you to apply to your recipes database.

**Update:** An example, based on the Logtalk object-oriented extension to Prolog (which you can use with most Prolog implementations, including GNU Prolog and SWI-Prolog). Several variations are possible. For hacking the concept of interface/protocol using instead modules see e.g. this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692835/define-parts-of-a-predicate-across-several-modules/21717456#21717456).

```
:- protocol(recipep).

    :- public([
        name/1, ingredient/3, step/1         % descriptors
    ]).

:- end_protocol.


:- object(proto_recipe, implements(recipep)).

    :- public([
        ingredient/1, ingredients/1, steps/1  % utility predicates
    ]).

    ingredient(Ingredient) :-
        ::ingredient(Ingredient,_,_).

    ingredients(Ingredients) :-
        findall(Ingredient, ::ingredient(Ingredient,_,_), Ingredients).

    steps(Steps) :-
        findall(Step, ::step(Step), Steps).

:- end_object.


:- object(green_soup, extends(proto_recipe)).

    name('Green Soup').

    ingredient(pea, 500, gr).
    ingredient(cream, 200, ml).

    step(...).
    ...

:- end_object.


:- object(mashed_peas, extends(proto_recipe)).

    name('Mashed Peas').

    ingredient(pea, 700, gr).
    ingredient(salt, 20, gr).
    ...

:- end_object.
```

Sample queries:

```
?- green_soup::ingredients(Ingredients).
Ingredients = [pea, cream].

?- conforms_to_protocol(Recipe, recipep), Recipe::ingredient(pea).
Recipe = green_soup ;
Recipe = mashed_peas ;
false.
```

Now assume that later you want to add a `level/1` descriptor to all recipes. Just for fun, let's use hot patching:

```
:- category(add_recipe_level_descriptor, complements(proto_recipe)).

    :- public(level/1).
    :- dynamic(level/1).

:- end_category.
```

You can now add your cooking experience. E.g. you always get into trouble while making green soup:

```
?- green_soup::assertz(level(hard)).
true.
```

But most recipes are easy, so let's add a default value to all recipes:

```
:- category(recipe_level_default_value, complements(proto_recipe)).

    level(easy).

:- end_category.
```

Now you can ask:

```
?- mashed_peas::level(Level).
Level = easy.
```

I have omitted some details (e.g. setup and compilation/loading steps) but hopefully this gives you an idea of what's possible (but full running example [here](https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/tree/master/examples/recipes)).

Comment: Thank you again for your input :) To be honest module or object representation is new for me in the context of Prolog. Maybe it would be oversized for my problem. I want not the fastest access to the database just a "not to silly one working". My main topic will be a dialog component, close to a "language understanding process", so that the user can type "I have an egg and a cup of cream left, what can I cook?". So the search in the database is limited to keywords as part of ingredients, recipenames or other descriptors of the recipe. [...]

Comment: [...]I do not need to keep the original XML structure, I need a representation in Prolog as I load the data when starting. So I suppose your first suggestion using `recipe(IDnumber,'Green Soup',ingredients([item(500,gramm,'pea'),item(200,ml,'cream')]),steps(['Do something','Next step do again something']))` based on lists as parameter is good enough. [...]

Comment: [...]Hopefully my last question: If I want to extend the data model to divide the list of ingredients in different parts, would it be a good idea to extend the list content like this: `recipe(IDnumber,'Green Soup',content([part('main dish', ingredients( [item(500,gramm,'pea'), item(200,ml,'cream')]), part('side dish', ingredients([item(200,gramm,'bread')]))]),steps(['Do something','Next step do again something']))` or do I complicate it to much?? You have to know, I am the first here using Prolog, so I am really, really happy about this platform and your input!!

Comment: A module/object representation is not over-sized for your problem. It would facilitate queries e.g. what can be cooked with this set of ingredients. It also make it more flexible to change recipe descriptions by e.g. adding new descriptors. A key point is that the it will provide you with an interface that you can use to abstract the details of the recipe representation to the client code that will access the recipe data. Of course, you can also approximate it by defining a set of access predicates and ensure that the recipes data is always accessed via those predicates rather than directly.

Comment: If you have the time, please give me a little example or a link to one how a module and such an interface then looks like. This would help me very much.

Comment: Done. I have expanded my answer with an example.

Comment: Wow! Great, great thanks! You are right, this is a very smart way to do it. I will go through it. :)

Answer (score 2):

SWI-Prolog offers library([xpath](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=xpath)), that allows referencing nodes and properties 'Prolog style'.
On backtracking the instantiations are returned to caller. So you can use in findall etc as you see best fit.

```
?- database(Db), xpath(Db, //recipe, Recipe).
```

will enumerate all recipes. The library is powerful, but not easy to learn. Look at the (meager) examples you see there...

You can also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9231426/874024), I answered suggesting `library(xpath)` to process GCC XML. I used it to build my SWI / OpenGL interface...

Comment: since you're already using the same XML representation used by SWI, maybe could be worth the effort to wrap your access predicates in a compatible interface. If you keep it to the basic, should be fairly simple to do... really, it boils down to having a 'lazy evaluation', as already performed by member/2, and custom pattern matching. Not too difficult...Additionally, it shows an important architectural point, namely how to handle **efficiently** large trees, using xpath_chk (mapped to memberchk, I think)

Comment: ...the similarity is because I started my first steps in SWI Prolog. Due to license specifics the decision here was made to use GNU Prolog... whereat with the problems running GNU Prolog (or gplc) on windows, too, it is maybe not the last decision...

Comment: your comment about licensing it's interesting. I used to think that SWI-Prolog is more permissive that GnuProlog, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: As far as I have understood our license discussion here, in principle for both the LGPL is valid but (1) for GNU Prolog it is described clearly that your own development compiled with gplc can be seen as separate development from a legal point of view. On the SWI Prolog website it is (as our IT expert says) not written so clearly, only that "SWI wants to use the same license principle as gcc does" (2) SWI Prolog includes packages with other license conditions.

Comment: Actually I do research but a possible deduction of a commercial product should be possible. I've found no clear statement that this is possible with SWI. You know one? I would be happy :)

Comment: For sure, I can't tell (I'm not a lawyer :). SWI has an exception on LGPL, that - afaik - relaxes further the terms. In brief, Jan Wielemaker stated informally that 'you can do whatever you want with it'. This is a common viewpoint, but your concerns should anyway apply only if you modify the interpreter itself, or some library. Otherwise, it's GPL, so I can't see the problem.

Comment: Thank you for "re-open" compiler discussion :) I just wrote an Email to JanW and it seems that you are right and hopefully I can switch back to SWI soon:)